# AngularJS : tree directive not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Creating an angular tree directive with an isolated scope that binds the value of two attributes...items and item-click-handler.  Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="TreeCtrl">
    <item-tree class="tree" items="treeFamily" item-click-handler="groupSelectedFunction(itemId)"></item-tree>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.controller("TreeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.treeFamily = [{
        Name : "Parent",
        Code : "Parent",
        Children: [{
            Name : "Child1",
            Code : "Child1",
            Children: [{
                Name : "Grandchild1",
                Code : "Grandchild1",
                Children: []
            },{
                Name : "Grandchild2",
                Code : "Grandchild2",
                Children: []
            },{
                Name : "Grandchild3",
                Code : "Grandchild3",
                Children: []
            }]
        }, {
            Name: "Child2",
            Code : "Child2",
            Children: []
        }]
    }];
    $scope.groupSelectedFunction = function (itemId) {
                alert(itemId + ' selected');
    }
});

module.directive("itemTree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            itemClickHandler: '&'
        },
        template: 
            '<ul id="group-nodes" ng-repeat="item in items">' +                
                '<li id={{ item.Code }}>' + 
                    '<a ng-click="itemClickHandler({itemId: 1})">{{ item.Name }}</a>'+
                    '<item-tree items="item.Children" item-click-handler="itemClickHandler(itemId)"></item-tree>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
            var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                if(!compiledContents) {
                    compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                }
                compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                         iElement.append(clone); 
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The tree builds fine.  If i click the top level parent node the controller function runs and shows an alert with the expected value: **"Parent selected"**.  However if any of the other nodes are clicked the the function runs but the alert message is: **"undefined selected"**.  Relatively new to Angular so this one has left me scratching my head.  Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what ID should be showing in the alert for each child node, but it is more obvious why you're seeing `undefined` instead of a value...

When using the `&` isolate scope type, the arguments passed to a function from a template need to be passed in an object, which you followed for the top level element:

```
ng-click="itemClickHandler({itemId: 1})"
```

You need to follow the same syntax for the children. So,

```
item-click-handler="itemClickHandler(itemId)"
```

should be

```
item-click-handler="itemClickHandler({itemId: itemId})"
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFP2BtWNO28PPvQtiTMU?p=preview)